# Using exponential powers in jq

Tags: json, jq

I get JSON objects containing a byte and I'm converting over to TB. Generally the way I prefer to do this is divide by 1024 to the 4th power.

I'm using `jq '.value|tonumber|(./(1024*1024*1024*1024))'`, but I'd prefer to replace the `1024*1024*1024*1024` with something like `1024**4` or `1024^4` is there anyway to do this in `jq`?  Is there another way I'm missing?

Data is simple and looks like this:

```
{
  "value": "43165913081459",
  "name": "AvailableStorage"
}
```

Comment: By the way, an alternate way to get KB, MB, GB and TB powers of 2 is to use 2^10, 2^20, 2^30, 2^40. At least that's how I remember it. A bit shorter for the bigger ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, only basic mathematical operations are available on numbers.  However, you should have access to [C Math](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Math) functions available on your platform. So a lot of what's in the cstdlib should be fair game, such as the [pow()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) function.

```
(.value | tonumber) / pow(1024; 4)
```

Otherwise, I'm not aware of any other approach, other than passing that in as an argument.

```
$ jq --argjson div "$((1024**4))" '(.value | tonumber) / $div' input.json
```

Comment: Thanks, though I realize now that I should have specified `jq` version 1.3 and it took me a while to realize you were using 1.5.  Your solutions worked well in 1.5 and gave me some clues to figuring out a 1.3 solution as below.  Accepting this solution.
    
    
1.3 solution:  
    `jq --arg div "$((1024**4))"  '(.value|tonumber) / ($div|tonumber) ' input.json`

Comment: IMHO exponents are a basic mathematical operation, but good to know they have pow() though. Thanks.